# How can i fix the animation on different DPI?

Tags: android, user-interface, dpi

I have an animation that move a png image to the top then it stop at certain position

the problem is that it stops on different position on different devices with different DPI

[image]

project structure

[image]

project link:
https://github.com/anggarisky/SplashtoHomeAngga

XML:

**bganim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    >

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="30%p"
        android:duration="800"
        />

</set>
```

**cloveranim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:startOffset="300"
    >


    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="800"
        />


</set>
```

**frombottom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    >

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="10%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="800"
        />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="600"
        />

</set>
```

**acitivty_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="272dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clover"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textsplash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Good Morning"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mr Panda Risky"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/texthome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Explore"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Simply makes design good"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.726"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bitcon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BitCoin"
                    android:textColor="#0E1843"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bellcon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bells"
                    android:textColor="#0E1843"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bookcon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Books"
                    android:textColor="#0E1843"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bugcon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reports"
                    android:textColor="#0E1843"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgapp"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="900dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bgapp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.309"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView bgapp, clover;
    LinearLayout textsplash, texthome, menus;
    Animation frombottom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frombottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.frombottom);


        bgapp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgapp);
        clover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clover);
        textsplash = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.textsplash);
        texthome = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.texthome);
        menus = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menus);

        bgapp.animate().translationY(-2400).setDuration(450).setStartDelay(1500);
        clover.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(600);
        textsplash.animate().translationY(140).alpha(0).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300);

        texthome.startAnimation(frombottom);
        menus.startAnimation(frombottom);


    }
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: i guess image view size is the problem. because it is depends on dpi. so you have to set size with percent like the animation. you can use constraintlayout as parent and set width and height with percent.

Comment: How can i set image view layout_height and image view layout_width with percent ? and the i'm already using ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the problem

the perfect value for the translationY for me is -1900 for 440dpi, so i did 1+00/440=4,318181818181818‬ so i can use 4,318181818181818‬ for 1dpi

```
float h = 4.318181818181818f;
DisplayMetrics dm = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
float tr=densityDpi*h;
bgapp.animate().translationY(-tr).setDuration(450).setStartDelay(1500);
```

i think this is not the perfect solution, but it work for now

Answer (score 0):

as i sayed i guess image view size is the problem. because it is depends on dpi. so you have to set size with percent like the animation. you can use constraintlayout as parent and set width and height with percent

like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"/>
```

Comment: didn't worked, did you tried it in your side ? check also the github repo

Comment: do you mean imageview percent size or animation? and check your constraintlayout version. mine is 1.1.3

Comment: didn't understand, i'm using 1.1.3 too
the "move up" animation controlled by java and bganim.xml, please check both of them

Comment: i see your code and some place in xml you use fix size like 900dp for width or height. you have to replace it with some thing that is base on percent. and you have some linearlayout. you can't use percent width or height for views inside them. the parent of view has too be constraintlayout for that